# QDir currentPath and cd() not working?

Tags: c++, qt, cd, qdir

I am currently attempting to create a new directory and create a new file inside of this directory. However, QDir recognizes that this file exists, however when I try to cd to my new directory, the currentPath returns the same value before and after the `QDir().cd(dirName)`

```
QDir().cdUp();
if(!QDir(dirName).exists())
  QDir().mkdir(dirName);
qDebug() << QDir().currentPath();    // returns a path up from exe dir
if(QDir().cd(dirName))
   qDebug() << QDir().currentPath(); //returns the same path as above
```

Really not sure why this isn't working, I am pretty new to programming and was wondering why this was.

Answer (score 3):

```
QDir().cd(dirName)
```

Every time you perform `QDir()` you're creating a new instance of the object, then you perform an operation on it (i.e., `.cd(dirName)`), and finally that object goes out of scope and is destroyed; thereby losing all your changes.

Instead you should be creating a single instance and performing all operations on it.

```
QDir dir;
dir.cd(dirName);
dir.path();
```

Comment: very nice explanation.

Comment: Wow I feel stupid...Thank you so much for this explanation

Answer (score 1):

The constructor `QDir()` creates a `QDir` object pointing to the program's working directory. `QDir()::cd()` changes that `QDir` object directory, however it does not change program directory. If you really want to change current application working directory, see [`QDir()::setCurrent(const QString & path)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#setCurrent)

That current application directory is used as relative path for files. So, to create a file in a new directory, you can specify the full file path or to use relative path as:

```
QDir::setCurrent(new_base_path);
QFile("some_relative_file_name");
...
```